# Loading HTML in the Ajax Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

So I am dealing with this weird service when returns a html page as the ajax response which has a form and the form is triggered automatically by some scripts in the page (so when you render the page a post request will be sent to you). What I am trying to do is to load this page I am getting from the response.

Say this is my Ajax call:

```
var ajax_call_test = function() {
    var formData = new FormData($('#documentForm')[0]);
    console.log("doc form: " + formData);

    $.ajaxSetup({
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    });

    $.ajax("/documents/upload/", {
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html){
            // ?
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("failed: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

So I tried to use `.html` to set the response to a hidden `<div>`. It sets the html but never triggers the form. I am guessing the javascript in that page is not loaded when I use `.html`.

I also cannot use `jQuery.parseHTML()` since the version of library I am using does not support that functionality. Any idea what should I do with response?

Comment: "/documents/upload/" <- I think this needs to be a page... eg: "/documents/upload/index.php" or something like that.

Comment: nope that should be just an end point and it works fine. I am getting the correct response back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ever you load new html into the DOM. The javascript does not know about it.

I have to re invoke my javascript to work with the new DOM.

Lets say I have some click events

```
$(function(){invokeClicks()}) // onload call

function invokeSomeAction(){
    $("selector").off(); // disable previous events from old html
    $("selector").on("event", function(){
        // handle event
    })
}

function invokeClicks(){
    invokeSomeAction();
    // ... etc
}
```

So when this JS loads, the `invokeClicks()` method gets called.

Now, if I replace the HTML through a `$.ajax()` call, all I have to do is call `invokeClicks()` again to clear the old events and now the new HTML will work with the javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: "somepath",
    data: {id: 1},
    method: "GET", 
    success: function(html){
         $("container_selector").html(html);
         invokeClicks(); // reinit
    },
})
```